# Why Vue can't resolve image from localhost?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

As a back-end for vue.js I use laravel (port 8000)

In my db I have the user and the name of it's profile photo (`this.user.photo`).

So, I want to show this photo.

```
<img :src="require(`http://localhost:8000/images/${this.user.photo}`)" alt="Profile Photo">
```

When I go to http://localhost:8000/images/1.png I actually see the image, but the Vue says:

> **Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http://localhost:8000'**

PS: `console.log(this.user.photo)` outputs `1.png`

UPD: I've seen many solutions, like [this](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/dynamic-image-paths-not-working/48785) or [this](https://ednsquare.com/question/dynamic-images-not-working-in-vue-js-------aUZHzV), but they do not work

Comment: Have you tried `require(\`../images/${this.user.photo}\`)` once.

Comment: That works, but I don't understand why..

Comment: Why are you using `require`? If the image is hosted directly at that URL, just use the URL directly like you would normally for an `<img>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your images are already hosted on the server and you are not bundling them during build. In this case, you need not use `require` and directly refer to your images in the template as

```
<img :src="'http://localhost:8000/images/' + user.photo" alt="Profile Photo">
```

Remember that `require` is a method provided by webpack to resolve your dependancy URLs during build such that you need not worry about the absolute URLs. `require` helps us refer to URLs relative to the modules which are resolved by webpack during build.

In short, use `require` when you have static assets inside your Vue project module

Answer (score 3):

You can call the image directly with path if the image is not in public path

```
 <img :src=`../../images/${user.photo}` alt="Profile Photo">
```

This will build image in the path where the compiling the JS and the image public path will automatically added.

If you're trying to add image from public path, you can initialise the origin path in the `data` section and call the image like follows

```
data:()=>{
  return {
    path: document.location.origin
  }
}

<img :src=`${path}/images/${user.photo}` alt="Profile Photo">
```

Note: you don't need to use `this` in the template section.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `require` and point to the image.

Make sure that the path is relative to the module that uses it.

Answer (score 2):

Write a function to return the image URL

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
 methods: {
    getPicture() {
      return 'https://vuejs.org/images/logo.png'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <img :src="getPicture()" alt="Profile Photo">
</div>
```