# Unable to display image in vue component form storage of Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-7

I am unable to display the image in vue component from the Storage directory of Laravel. Please help me to solve this issue:

images are stored in DB as `public/avatar/TSD50oeYXnkrX1nQ38N9zljP1FRdP42yPhJOrEKg.png`

if I remove public path and do this `<img :src="'../storage/avatar/31deG4gnbO3EwO2s26lnUe0KzJjskFfm8lPIGFeM.jpeg'" width="100">`

i can see image diplayed in vue component from storage/public/avatar folder

method to get details of single user

```
public function user($id){
        return $user = User::find($id);
    }
```

methods to save image

```
public function profilePic(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request,[
            'image'=>'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png'
        ]);
        $image = $request->image->store('public/avatar');
        $authUser = auth()->user()->id;
        $user = User::where('id',$authUser)->update([
            'profilePic'=> $image
        ]);
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

vue:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Profile Component</div>

            {{user.profilePic}}
//how can i display image here


<div class="card-body">
                        <form @submit.prevent="updateProfilePic" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control"v-on:change="onImageChange">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props:['userid'],
        data(){
            return{
                image:'',
                user:[]

            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getUser()
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        },
        methods:{
            onImageChange(e){
                console.log(e)
                this.image = e.target.files[0];

                },
            updateProfilePic(){
                const config={
                    headers:{
                        "content-type":"multipart/form-data"
                    }
                }
                let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('image',this.image);

                axios.post('/profile-pic',formData,config).then((response)=>{
                    this.image='';
                    this.getUser()



                }).catch((error)=>{
                    console.log(error)
                    this.allerrors = error.response.data.errors
                })
            },
            getUser(){
                axios.get('/user/'+this.userid).then((response)=>{
                    this.user = response.data
                }).catch((error)=>{
                    alert('some error')
                })
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

To make these files accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`.
to create the symbolic link run this:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

then in vue component :

```
<img :src="'/storage/images'+filename" width="100">
```

but if you have a array of categories , every category has a image

```
 <img v-for="category in categories" :key="category.id" :src="'/storage/' + category.image" alt=""  />
```

`category.image` equal `images/ScjDpeUs12vvJHouHTWXQ12BBghzBoImDiumuNPx.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

you can display the image like this.[Here is a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61097508/why-vue-cant-resolve-image-from-localhost/61097836#61097836)

```
<img :src="'/avatar/' + user.profilePic" alt="Profile Photo">
```

Comment: This is not working for me image path is public/avatar/filename.jpg

Comment: Does  this display the inage ? <img :src="'../storage/avatar/31deG4gnbO3EwO2s26lnUe0KzJjskFfm8lPIGFeM.jpeg'" width="100">

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you didn't set the symbolic link between storage and public folders.
Try running this command: `php artisan storage:link`

You can learn more here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: In which folder your images are directly located? and what is your default storage driver?

Comment: Hi images are in storage/public/avatar/filename.png