# Display dynamic image in VueJs with Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to display image stored in storage/app/public/images folder with VueJS but somehow the image is not displayed
in vue file

```
 <img v-bind:src="img" />

 export default {
    data(){
    return{
        img:'',
    };
},
   mounted() {
        axios.get('/api/image')
        .then(res => {
            this.img = res.data
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    },
```

The path returned is correct, however the image is not shown.

Kindly help

Comment: can you share the exact image link that you are getting

Answer (score 1):

Create a function to return the photo

```
<img class="profile-pic" :src="getProfilePhoto()" alt="profile-pic">

 getProfilePhoto() { // return default if image is null
        var photo = (this.img == null) ? "/images/user.jpg" : this.img
         return photo
    },
```

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61097508/why-vue-cant-resolve-image-from-localhost/61097836#61097836)

With a working example.